# No console output from code

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a simple script I can use for a JavaScript/HTML RPG game, but when building the battle script, I no getting any console output. I have tried everything I can think of but still no luck and I started to wonder if I've made a coding error somewhere.

```
var player = {hp:100, attack:10, defence:10, speed:20};
var enemy = {hp:100, attack:10, defence:10, speed:20};

function playeratk(){
    console.log("enemy " + enemy.hp);
    var pAtk = Math.floor(Math.random() * player.attack) + 1;
    console.log(pAtk);
    enemy.hp = enemy.hp - pAtk;
    console.log("enemy " + enemy.hp);
    console.log("-----");
}

function enemyatk(){
    console.log("player " + player.hp);
    var eAtk = Math.floor(Math.random() * enemy.attack) + 1;
    console.log(eAtk);
    player.hp = player.hp - eAtk;
    console.log("player " + player.hp);
    console.log("-----");
}


function battle() {
    if (player.hp < 1) {
        console.log("Enemy wins");
    }
    else if (enemy.hp < 1){
        console.log("Player Wins");
    }
    else {
        var pSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * player.speed) + 1;
        var eSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * enemy.speed) + 1;
        if (player.speed > enemy.speed){
            playeratk();
            enemyatk();
            battle();
        }
        else if(enemy.speed > player.speed){
            enemyatk();
            playeratk();
            battle();
        }
        else {
            playeratk();
            enemyatk();
            battle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you aren't calling any function. At least, not in this code.

Comment: You need to call the function, try placing this somewhere `battle()` outside of the functions, if it doesn't call by itself, then either trigger the function by an event. like .click then trigger the function.

Comment: Notice anything wrong with?  `<script>function why() { console.log("Why won't you print!!!"); }</script>`  Hint: you actually need to call the functions that you defined.

Comment: Thank you soo much! It's been driving me crazy. I've only been learning JS for about a week now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the `battle()` function at least once outside of itself. Maybe at the end of the script.